# Configuring Multiple Applications with Different PHP Versions on Apache

Tags: php, apache

I have four applications—namely, applo, appli, appla, and appZa —all of which were originally designed to function with PHP 5.6. Recently, I decided to upgrade the appZa application to PHP 8. As a result, I am now encountering challenges in configuring the Apache server on Windows (utilizing the httpd.conf file) to accommodate this mix of PHP versions.

My objective is to ensure that applo, appli, and appla continue working seamlessly with PHP 5, while enabling the recently upgraded appZa to operate with PHP 8.

Given this scenario, could you kindly provide guidance on how I can adjust the Apache configuration to achieve this segregated PHP version setup for the mentioned applications?

in httpd-vhosts.conf i modify my file to be :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
   <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/appZa/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    SetHandler "php82-handler"
    LoadModule php_module "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/php/php8.2.7/php8apache2_4.dll"
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but doesn't work

Comment: You can only have one mod_php loaded at once. You can try a different SAPI, such as mod_fcgid. Binaries can be found [here](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/) and documentation is [here](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/).

Comment: Running multiple versions of PHP in the same web server is always more trouble than it's worth. You're likely better off just migrating the converted apps to a new server or a container-based service.